# After upgrade Rails 3 .0. to 7.0 I am getting retrieve_connection': No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    30: from script/rails:6:in `require'
    29: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    27: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    26: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    25: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    24: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    23: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    22: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `tap'
    21: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
    20: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `require'
    19: from /home/sharique/Desktop/CodeSlash/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/acts_as_audited-2.0.0/lib/acts_as_audited.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/acts_as_audited-2.0.0/lib/acts_as_audited.rb:36:in `require'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/acts_as_audited-2.0.0/lib/acts_as_audited/audit.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/acts_as_audited-2.0.0/lib/acts_as_audited/audit.rb:25:in `<class:Audit>'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:22:in `order'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:429:in `order'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:434:in `order!'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1591:in `preprocess_order_args'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:93:in `connection'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:208:in `retrieve_connection': No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found. (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 -> 7 is not going to be a smooth upgrade, there's a LOT of work involved.  I mean `script/rails` doesn't even exist anymore.

Honestly, 3 is so old there's no "right way" to upgrade from 3 to 7.  I think the easiest option is to create a blank Rails 3 project, and a blank Rails 7 project, and then use `diff` to look at the differences and apply those differences to your project.  Then you'll still need to upgrade most of the gems in the project.

Just to put you in the ballpark, I've done these sorts of upgrades professionally, and the time required is around the 40-80 hour mark.